# Sufficient condition for time-changed quadratic covariation to vanish in probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $(M_t^n)_{t \geq 0}$ be a sequence of continuous martingales of the form $M^n_t = \int_0^t X^n_s \, dB_s$ where $B_s$ is a Brownian motion. Let $\tau^n(t)$ be the time change associated to $M_t^n$ via the Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz theorem, i.e. $\tau^n(t) = \inf \, \{s \mid \langle  M^n,M^n \rangle_s > t \}$ and we have that $M_t^n = \widetilde{B}_{\tau^n(t)}$, where $\widetilde{B}$ is another Brownian motion and $\langle M^n,M^n \rangle_t$ denotes the quadratic variation of $M^n_t$.

I'm reading a paper and can't figure out the following statement:

"*In order for $\langle M^n,B \rangle_{\tau^n(t)}$ to converge to zero in probability (for $n \to \infty$), it is sufficient to show that $\langle M^n,B \rangle_{t}$ converges to zero in probability, uniformly in $t$ on compact sets.*"

How does one prove this? Is this true for any stopping time?

What the authors in fact show is uniform convergence in $L^p$, i.e. that $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} \operatorname{E} \left[ \left| \langle M^n,B \rangle_{t} \right|^p \right]$ converges to zero for $n \to \infty$, any $p \geq 2$ and any $T>0$, but this also doesn't give me an idea for a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the statement written in Italic is false. A counterexample would be this: $M^n(s) = B(s-n)I_{s \geq n}$, where $B$ is a BM, and $N^n = M^n$. In this case, $\tau^n(t) = t+n$,

$$
\langle M^n,N^n \rangle_{\tau^n(t)} = t \nrightarrow 0 , n \to \infty
$$

but $\langle M^n,N^n \rangle_{t} \to 0$ uniformly on compacts even a.s., since 
$\langle M^n,N^n \rangle_{t} = 0\ $ whenever $n>t$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the counterexample, Sinusx, this shows that I was to eager to abstract details away, which are apparently very important. I have reformulated my question, adding these details. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: Hm, $M^n$ does not depend on $n$, if $M^n_t = \int_0^t X_s \, dB_s$. Do you mean $M^n_t = \int_0^t X_s ^n \, dB_s$?

Comment: By the way, which paper do you read?

Comment: Yes, I meant $X^n_s$, thanks (corrected it)! I'm reading this paper: [http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2473]. The convergence in question is written in eq. 3.12 on page 6.

Comment: Well, I think the same counterexample may be given, with $X^n_t = I _{t \geq n} $. I did not read the paper, maybe, they have some ohter conditions?

Comment: I finally figured it out (and I'm quite embarased to write this): The above statement inside my original question is false, as seen by the counterexamples of @Sinusx. The authors formulated things a bit complicated and what they actually say is that both convergences are sufficient to draw a certain conclusion (a Theorem from another reference). This can be seen by going through the proof of the other reference. Anyway, thanks for your help!